# Legend in Matlab in for loop

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I have a for loop that looks somewhat like these:

```
RowToPlot =2;
Num=2;
SwatchToPlots=[2 3];
DataToGraph=rand(168,97);
[RowsData,ColsData]=size(DataToGraph);
x=1:RowsData;

figure
for idx=1:Num
    SwatchToPlot=SwatchToPlots(1,idx);
    if RowToPlot==1
        if SwatchToPlot==1
            plot(x,DataToGraph(:,22:25));hold on;
            legend('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4');
        elseif SwatchToPlot==2
            plot(x,DataToGraph(:,46:49));hold on;
            legend('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4');
        elseif SwatchToPlot==3
            plot(x,DataToGraph(:,70:73));hold on;
            legend('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4');
        elseif SwatchToPlot==4
            plot(x,DataToGraph(:,94:97));hold on;
            legend('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4');
        end
    elseif RowToPlot==2
        if SwatchToPlot==1
            plot(x,DataToGraph(:,18:21));hold on;
            legend('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4');
        elseif SwatchToPlot==2
            plot(x,DataToGraph(:,42:45));hold on;
            legend('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4');
        elseif SwatchToPlot==3
            plot(x,DataToGraph(:,66:69));hold on;
            legend('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4');
        elseif SwatchToPlot==4
            plot(x,DataToGraph(:,90:93));hold on;
            legend('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3', 'ex4');
        end
    end
end
```

Each plot line plots 4 lines in the y axis, and depending on the value in Num, the for loop could repeat and more lines could be plotted. If the for loop happens only one time, then I can easily add a legend using the legend() function. However, if the for loop happens more than once, the new legend does not append to the existing legend. How can I append the legend to the already existing legend, instead of just replacing it?

*Note: I've read similar questions but can't still make it work given that I'm plotting four y lines using a single plot() function.

Comment: "I've read similar questions but can't still make it work given that I'm plotting four y lines using a single plot() function." Please show what it is that you tried, it'll make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to always provide a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Since that was not provided, I wrote a dummy script underlying the usage of legend command within loops.

```
close all; clc;

t = 0:0.01:10; % time vec
w = 1;         % fixed frequency in rad

arrayLimiter = length(t);
% create some sine signals with phase delay for demo purposes
signal1 = zeros(arrayLimiter, 1);
signal2 = zeros(arrayLimiter, 1);
signal3 = zeros(arrayLimiter, 1);

for i = 1:arrayLimiter
  signal1(i) = sin(2*pi*w*t(i) + 0);
  signal2(i) = sin(2*pi*w*t(i) + 30);
  signal3(i) = sin(2*pi*w*t(i) + 60);
end

figure; 
hold on; grid on; set(gcf, 'color', 'w'), ylim([-2 2]),
for i = 1:3
  plot(t, signalArr(:, i), 'DisplayName', ['Singal ', num2str(i)]),
end
legend show,
```

Which gives the following output: [image: plot]
You can programmatically add as many legend entries along with signals, using the "DisplayName" functionality of the plot function. Let me know if anything is unclear.